# Como (Re)usar GoogleApiClient em recyclerview e adapter

Tags: android-recyclerview, google-api

Estou usando **Google Places API for Android** para sugestão de endereços em campos de entrada. Esta API usa **GoogleAPIClient** para operar.

O `app` tem um fragmento composto por um `recyclerview` e um `FAB`.

Ao tocar o `FAB`, o usuário abre um diálogo com form. de entrada. Neste form. tem um campo `AutoCompleteTextView` para inserir o endereço. Este campo tem um **adapter** para o **GoogleAPIClient** e mostra sugestões de endereços a medida que o usuário entra com os dados.

Esta parte esta pronta.

A medida que dados são inseridos, o `recyclerview` vai mostrando estes dados em cards. Ao clicar num card, outro dialogo é aberto, desta vez para edição dos dados.

E aqui que está o problema. Não estou sabendo usar o **GoogleAPIClient** no adapter do recyclerview.

Tentei criar um outro **GoogleAPIClient** na classe que extende `RecyclerView.Adapter`, mas não soube fazer ou não é por aí.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recycler, container, false);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();

    mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            BOUNDS_AUTOCOMPLETE, null);
```

Este é o código do `onCreateView` do fragment. Tentei instanciar o mGoogleApiClient no `onCreateViewHolder` e no `onBindViewHolder, ele não aceita nada como 1º parametro de`enableAutoManage`.

**A pergunta é:** como eu faço para usar o **GoogleApiClient** num fragmento que tem recyclerciew e também em eventos dos itens deste mesmo recyclerview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não houve resposta -- ganhei até medalha por isso -- e resolvi o problema do `app`, aqui vai minha conclusão.

Não é possível reaproveitar as conexões com o `GoogleApiClient`. Cada classe deve fazer sua conexão, a não ser que o cliente seja criado como objetivo estático. Mas usar objetos estáticos é contra indicado, devido ao efeitos colaterais que podem ocorrer no processamento em threads.

Sendo assim, cada segmento do aplicativo deve criar um cliente de API. E evitar o uso do método `enableAutoManage()` controlando o estado do objeto manualmente.

Se alguém quiser me corrigir ou adicionar mais informações, fique a vontade.